# How do I show Current Academic Year?

Tags: powerbi

Please see table below, whereby I need some M code to create the yellow column. Every day, this table will refresh with today's date as per the code, and I need some M code which will automatically populate the correct `YearCode` in the `YearCodeToday` column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Table.SelectRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectrows) for that, so the M code could be like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtA3VNJRMtSz0ANxgExjQz1zENtQKVYHrMJQ3wihwhBJhRFMhZG+MUKFEZIKY6XYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [YearCode = _t, YearStart = _t, YearEnd = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "YearCodeToday", (t) => Table.SelectRows(Source, each DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= DateTime.Date(DateTime.FromText([YearStart])) and DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) <= DateTime.Date(DateTime.FromText([YearEnd]))){0}),
    #"Expanded YearCodeToday" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "YearCodeToday", {"YearCode"}, {"YearCode.1"})
in
    #"Expanded YearCodeToday"
```

And you will get the result bellow (I removed `Today` column, because it wasn't needed):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. I've written the code you've specified above but I keep getting a 'record' rather than data in the column. Then when I expand the new field I get 'nulls'.

Comment: If you get a record, then probably you missed something, but just expand the record using the button in the column title.

Comment: Does my code look right? I've omitted the top part:

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Dimension_AcademicYear,{{"AcademicYearEndDate", type text}, {"AcademicYearStartDate", type text}}),
 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "YearCodeToday", (t) => Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= DateTime.Date(DateTime.FromText([AcademicYearStartDate])) and DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) <= DateTime.Date(DateTime.FromText([AcademicYearEndDate]))){0}),
    YearCodeToday = #"Added Custom"{0}[YearCodeToday]
in
    YearCodeToday

Comment: I've just checked and it has worked so thank you so much, Andrey! Much appreciated it!